# How to extract text from a string with Python using indexing and slicing

Tags: python

I am trying to extract certain character from a variable using Python Indexing an Slicing. I have the following variable

```
myvar = 
'https://mystorageacct.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/29112013 FDD_Exec Summary 29 Nov 2013.pdf'
```

I am trying to extract

> 29112013 FDD_Exec Summary 29 Nov 2013

I have tried such indexing as

grab = myvar[:10] but the result doesn't give me 29112013 FDD_Exec Summary 29 Nov 2013.

Any thoughts?

Comment: why do you expect `myvar[:10]` to give you `29112013 FDD_Exec Summary 29 Nov 2013`?  `myvar[:10]` will give you the first 10 chars of `myvar`

Comment: you can do what you want with slicing like that, but you have to choose the right numbers to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myvar = 'https://mystorageacct.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/29112013 FDD_Exec Summary 29 Nov 2013.pdf'

# Split the string by '/' and you get a list of 
# ['https:', '', 'mystorageacct.blob.core.windows.net', 'testcontainer','29112013 FDD_Exec Summary 29 Nov 2013.pdf']

# [-1] index is to pick the last one
# .replace('.pdf','') is to remove the '.pdf'
extract = myvar.split('/')[-1].replace('.pdf','')
print(extract)

>>> 29112013 FDD_Exec Summary 29 Nov 2013
```

Answer (score 3):

I might suggest using `str.rpartition` so that you don't need to separately go through the work of figuring out which indices to slice on:

```
>>> myvar = 'https://mystorageacct.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/29112013 FDD_Exec Summary 29 Nov 2013.pdf'
>>> myvar.rpartition("/")[2]
'29112013 FDD_Exec Summary 29 Nov 2013.pdf'
>>> myvar.rpartition("/")[2].rpartition(".")[0]
'29112013 FDD_Exec Summary 29 Nov 2013'
```

Comment: so, sam I tried to include your suggestion ```myvar2 = myvar.rpartition("/")[2].rpartition(".")[0]``` into the following  ```df_data.to_csv(r"/dbfs/mnt/pdf-recognized/FinalInvestmentReport/{}.txt", index=False).format("myvar2") but I get the following error ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'```

Comment: That just means that `df_data.to_csv(r"/dbfs/mnt/pdf-recognized/FinalInvestmentReport/{}.txt", index=False)` returned `None`.  Nothing to do with `myvar2`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the built-in `pathlib` for anything having to do with filepaths. Seems to work fine for URLs:

```py
import pathlib

filename = pathlib.Path(myvar).name
```

Output:

```py
'29112013 FDD_Exec Summary 29 Nov 2013.pdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last 10 characters, you could use:

```
myvar[-10:]
```

so: start from the 10th to last character and go to the last.

If this should be more general, you would look at your strings structure and split it, e.g. by spaces and then take the correct value